# args in soap client js

Tags: javascript, soap, args

i m using soap module as defined in https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap to generate a client.
this is basically my soap client code

```
    var soap = require('soap');


     var url = 'http://example.com/wsdl?wsdl';


     var args = {name: 'value'};
        soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
           client.MyFunction(args, function(err, result) {
           console.log(result);
         });
      });
```

i have a problem using args.

how to build args to get such below soap request done with soap ui. notably what about minorversion, major version? how to add v1 naming space before each parameter? i thought that it was automatically built.

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:wsdl="http://xxxx/wsdl" xmlns:v1="http://uri.etsi.org/TS102204/v1.1.2#">

<soap:Body>
<wsdl:MSS_Signature>
     <MSS_SignatureReq MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1" MessagingMode="synch">
        <v1:AP_Info AP_ID="xxx" AP_TransID="cc" AP_PWD="yyy" Instant="2018-04-13T11:53:15.384+02:00"/>
        <v1:MobileUser>
           <v1:MSISDN>+xxxxx</v1:MSISDN>
        </v1:MobileUser>
        <v1:DataToBeSigned MimeType="?" Encoding="?">"text_blabla"</v1:DataToBeSigned>
        <v1:SignatureProfile>
           <v1:mssURI>xxx</v1:mssURI>
        </v1:SignatureProfile>
     </MSS_SignatureReq>
  </wsdl:MSS_Signature>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

currently i am only able to do this awful soap request far from targetted one with soapui and it is with the same wsdl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" >
<soap:Body>
<undefined:MSS_Signature>
<MessagingMode>xx</MessagingMode>
<AP_ID>xx</AP_ID>
<AP_PWD>xx</AP_PWD>
<AP_TransID>xx</AP_TransID>
<Instant>2018-05-01T09:00:00</Instant>
<MSISDN>+xx</MSISDN>
<DataToBeSigned>xxx</DataToBeSigned>
<SignatureProfile>xxx</SignatureProfile>
</undefined:MSS_Signature>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: and hello for sure :)

Comment: What problem(s) are you having exactly? Are you getting any errors, are you unsure how to use `args` on the SOAP side, or is it just not doing anything at all?

Comment: în fact the soap request is not well formatted compared to when i m using soap ui.

Comment: If you have additional code, then it is best to edit your question and add the code so that it can be in a more readable format.

Comment: i updated the post travisw. Yes i dont know how to use args properly notably to have  the line :<MSS_SignatureReq MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="1" MessagingMode="synch">

Comment: i managed to have attributes now except for the first element :(. but the namespace is still not correct :(. any idea?